# how to show variable's value in pop up dialog with java swing

Tags: java, swing

I am a beginner in programming. I was messing around with java swing and tried to make a silly app. This is my code. It's not showing any errors, but it's not working. When the dialog pops up, the variable's value doesn't show on the dialog. The logic i used is right, because when i run it in the compiler without the GUI stuff, it works perfectly. If anyone could tell what am i doing wrong in here, it would be really helpful.

this is my code for the calculations.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class swingApp extends JFrame{
    JLabel label;
    JButton button;
    public JLabel label2;
    JTextField textField = new JTextField("enter you nicknamae");
    String username=textField.getText();
    public int geniusMeter;
    public int sum=0;
    public String sumAsString;
    public void swingAppLogic(String name){
        char[] letters = username.toCharArray();
        char [] alphabet={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
        int [] measure={7,3,1,13,8,26,15,18,2,5,22,20,16,9,5,11,23,12,25,6,4,21,24,14,17,10};

        for(int count=0;count<letters.length;count++){
            for (int count1=0;count1<alphabet.length;count1++){
                if (letters[count]==alphabet[count1]){
                    geniusMeter=measure[count1];
                    sum=sum+geniusMeter;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        sumAsString = Integer.toString(sum);

    }

    public swingApp(){
        super("Genius Calculator");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        label = new JLabel("Wanna know how genius you are?"); 
        label2 = new JLabel(" ");
        button = new JButton("press enter and then click me to know the results");
        handlerClass handler = new handlerClass();
        button.addActionListener(handler);
        add(label);
        add(label2);
        add(button);
        add(textField);
    }
    public class handlerClass implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, sumAsString, "Title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        }
    }
}
```

and this is my main method

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class swingAppTester{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        swingApp object=new swingApp();

        object.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        object.setSize(500,400);
        object.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not call the swingAppLogic() method anywhere which calculates the value of sumAsString.

Comment: so what can i do to fix it?where should i call the method?

Comment: The solution is in hamena314's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use your method `swingAppLogic(String name)` in the `actionPerformed()`-method of the button:

```
public class handlerClass implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
      swingAppLogic(textField.getText());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, sumAsString, "Title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Another problem is, that your sum keeps getting bigger with every run. You need to reset it to 0 at every start:

```
public void swingAppLogic(String name){
    sum = 0;
    char[] letters = username.toCharArray();
```

It would also be helpful for you, if you learn a bit about coding standards. For instance class names should start with an uppercase letter to stop confusion in the code. And naming a `JLabel label` gets confusing incredibly fast when you have more than a handful.

hth!

PS: Your logic for calculating the genius sum seems to output always the same value of 150?

**[EDIT]:**

You are trying to get the name from the textfield that the user has entered. But you are doing this at the wrong time, while the textfield still contains "enter your nickname". So instead of `username.toCharArray()` use `name.toCharArray()`. The variable `username` then isn't needed anymore.

Comment: thanks!that seemed to work!but can you please explain a bit what we did there? did we bring a whole new variable to take the user input?

Comment: I got it.it's the variable in the parameter i passed in the method

Comment: That is correct. You give your method the parameter so it can work with it, therefore you've already named it `name`. This shows, that you should always give parameters, variables etc. correct and "talking" names, so you can see later on what variable / parameter is doing what. Example: A better name for `JTextField textField` might be `nicknameTextField`, so now you know what's inside when you read the source code later on.

Comment: Was my answer correct? If yes, could you please accept the answer? Or do you have any further questions regarding your question? :)